# Facebook url likes to page like

Tags: facebook

Today I have a like-button set up for the pages url. In the near future I might
Want to create a facebook page or group for the site.

Is there a way to move or sync the likes for the url with the page. Or will they always be separated and thus the gained like count lost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I 301 redirect a page in the open graph and retain facebook like information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-301-redirect-a-page-in-the-open-graph-and-retain-facebook-like-informa)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your old code for like button to have like link for the group page

```
   <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=
"your page link"
&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: ok, but then the people who liked the url will not be shown anymore?

Comment: I tried this `<fb:like href="->new page/group url<-" show_faces="true" width="225" font=""></fb:like>` but it did not work unfortunately. did I do what you meant?

Comment: as I know, we can't give custom url in  fbxml . 
you have to use js sdk.

Comment: I tried your solution with iframe but it did not work either, and I do not think it will since the button has no connection with the last, so why should the like count be transferred?

Comment: oh sorry. 
yes. your past count will get lost. 
my solution can only link two pages  future like count 
with a dummy url. 
you can have it like